# Whats wrong with my keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, shift

I have a new kind of weird problem with my laptops keyboard.

To be precise with the shift key. Lately the both Shift-Keys doesn't just make the letters upper case, they also took role of the 2 and the 7 on the numpad.
So when I push the left shift key (with num lock) it also writes a 7. When I use the left shift key (without num lock), the cursor goes to the begin of the line.
When i push the right shift key (with num lock) it writes a 2. When I use the right shift key (without num lock), the cursor goes to the end of the line.

I really don't know what I changed on the computer... it's really weird and really annoying

Comment: Is this a laptop? Can you specify what model and/or take a photo of the keyboard? I can’t help but wonder if it’s a `Fn` key/Numpad/etc. issue.

Comment: @Synetech -- Good point!  Before replacing the keyboard (and after trying toggling all the "odd" lock keys at the upper right) it's worth a shot trying a "cold boot" -- power down, remove battery for 10 minutes, reinstall battery, power up.  This will reset any wayward keyboard settings.

Answer (score 2):

The keyboard has somehow become damaged, you will need to replace it.

The issue is you have a laptop and it may not be that easy.

I would suggest buying a USB keyboard first to confirm this fixes the error. You may have to send it to the manufacturer for a fix sadly.

However, as a real shot in the dark, you could try

- Open Control Panel
- Open Regional and Language Options
- Select the Languages tab
- In the 'Text services and input languages' box, click the [Details] button
- In the Tex Services and Input Languages dialog box, check the 'Turn off all advanced text services' box under System Configuration

If that doesn't work, you may want to try to re-install the drivers of the keyboard but my money is on you'll need a new one.

Comment: It's worth a shot to take the laptop, with the lid closed, hold it vertically, and "lightly bang" the edge on a desk, hitting it from all 4 corners.  This may dislodge any dirt caught inside.  But if the problem is due to a beverage spilled on the keyboard there may be no fix other than replacement.

Comment: Actually, if it is by a drink then you can easily do the replacement yourself as I did when my wife spilled her bayley's all over my laptop!!

Comment: So how's the new wife working out?

Comment: DanH - New wife eats biscuits so now I get crumbs stopping the keys working :)  @Neifen, is this still an issue?